# Report Viewer(Visual Studio) Error: use a custom assembly with a RDLC report

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, dll, reporting-services, reportviewer

- I am trying to add a dll to Report Viewer so that I can decode one of the fields content(in the report) using the method from that dll.
- I have added a dll in Report Properties --> References.
- All the methods in the class library(used for creating dll) are static.
- The contents of the class in that class library: ABCClass.cs(used for creating the dll ABCCollection.dll)

  ```
  namespace ABCCollection
      {
          public class ABCClass
          {
             public static string CustomFormatString(string s)
              { 
                   //perform some operation on s
                   return s;
              }
          }
       }
  ```

In the Report1.rdlc, I am using value for a field as:

```
=ABCCollection.ABCClass.CustomFormatString("testing")
```

But once I run this report, I am getting error as:

```
 Error while loading code module: ‘ABCCollection, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null’. Details: Could not load file or assembly 'ABCCollection, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

When compiling your DLL check the namespace given by the properties of the project, generally it will be the name of the project. In this case, you are actually defining the namespace twice. So to call it from the DLL created it would be:

ABCCollection.ABCCollection.ABCClass.CustomFormatString("testing")

Answer (score 0):

The only way to make it happen is by adding your assembly to the gac.
There is a good example [**here**](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/dknight/2012/01/26/ssrs-custom-code-with-external-assemblies/).

In the end, it all gets down to this:

1. Create a separate project **ABCCollection.dll**
2. **Sign it** using visual studio project properties window, cause else you want be able to add it to the gac.
3. **gacutil** -if "path to ABCCollection.dll"
4. Don't forget to add "**[assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers()]**" to your ABCCollection/AssemblyInfo.cs file, or else you want be able to call the functions.

And you are done!